# How to check element visibility in expression?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two divs. I only want to show the first one if someExpression (using FirstController scope) is true. The second div should adapt and set a class based on if the first div is shown. The first div:

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-show='someExpression' ng-controller='FirstController' id='first'></div>
```

The second div:

```
<div ng-class="document.getElementById('first').style == 'none' ? 'col-md-8' : 'col-md-12'" ng-controller='SecondController'></div>
```

I'd rather use some more angular way than the one above (which I haven't got to work anyway). So - is there a way to detect if the first div is visible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will advise to use service to share data between controllers ie:

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.service('shared', function() {

  var visisble = true;

  return {
    visisble: visisble
  };

});

app.controller('FirstController', function($scope, shared) {
  $scope.someExpression = shared;
});


app.controller('SecondController', function($scope, shared) {
  $scope.someExpression = shared;

  $scope.update = function() {
    shared.visisble = !shared.visisble;


  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="first" ng-controller="FirstController" class="col-xs-4" ng-show="someExpression.visisble">
      <div>expresion {{someExpression.visisble}}</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="SecondController" ng-class=" someExpression.visisble ?'col-xs-8' :'col-xs-12'">
      <button ng-click="update()">show/hide</button>expresion {{someExpression.visisble}}</div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jQuery

```
angular.element('#first').hasClass('ng-hide')
```

Comment: Strangely, this won't work. Otherwise I like it, because it's the solution with the fewest bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Since the visibility of the first element is controlled by you (`someExpression`), then the second could be:

```
<div ng-class="{'col-md-8': someExpression, 'col-md-12': !someExpression}"
    ng-controller='SecondController'></div>
```

I.e. you use `someExpression` and `!someExpression` to control which classes are applied. Note the quotes around the class names.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work since the expression is depending on the scope of FirstController.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `someExpression` is bound to the `FirstController` (if not then just use the same expression in the `ng-class`)...

On the HTML:

```
ng-class="isVisible('first') ? 'red' : 'blue'"
```

On the *SecondController*:

```
$scope.isVisible = function(el) {
  return angular.element(document.getElementById(el)).hasClass('ng-hide');
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/844rydYVX3ix00NCn5az?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a directive, but its tough to do programmatically with two different controllers.

http://jsfiddle.net/f4epLhww/

AngularJS

```
var app = angular.module('divsApp', []);

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.visible = true;
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

});

app.directive('visible', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.visible) {
                $('#second-div').show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="divsApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <div ng-show="visible" visible>First Div</div>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl" style="display:none;" id="second-div">Second Div</div>
</div>
```